# JavaScript alternatives underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What are some non `prototype` modifying libraries that provide core functionality to JavaScript (not DOM, but Array,String,Number,RegExp,etc... manipulations)?

I'm looking for alternatives to underscore.js (jQuery doesn't count).

Comment: Underscore does not modify native prototypes. Why do you need an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few:

- [async](https://github.com/caolan/async): provides some asynchronous functions for arrays like `map` and `sortBy`.
- [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/)
- [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[lodash](http://lodash.com/) have very good functionaliy like underscore js and it is fast also compare to underscore js.

though lodash is good but i found another good library 
[SugarJS](http://sugarjs.com/)

Comment: "*Sugar adds methods to native Javascript objects*" - that's not what the OP asked for

Answer (score 1):

Oliver Steele's `Functional` (see [here](https://github.com/osteele/functional-javascript) or [here](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/)) covers a lot of the same problem space as Underscore.

Comment: there were no commits for two years :(

Comment: Yes, but that's kind of the way with mature software, no obvious need to continue developing something that's comprehensive and has no obvious bugs.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to underscore.js, [Valentine](https://github.com/ded/valentine) might be worth looking at.